# Converting iPad app to iPhone - xib size issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, xib

I'm trying to implement iPad app in iPhone, The steps i followed are

1. Copied the existing `.xib` of first view controller and renamed it to `name_iPhone.xib`
2. Enabled size class and auto layouts for `name_iPhone.xib`
3. Kept the size for view as `Inferred`

Now i am printing the screen width(`self.view.frame`) in log.

```
NSLog(@"View Frame : %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));
```

The result is

```
View frame : {{0, 0}, {600, 600}} //this is the results regardless of any device i run
```

Actually the log should print the device(in which i am running the app) dimensions, But it always prints 600*600 regardless of device in which app is running. How to automatically resize the root view of a controller according to device dimensions.
Please help me finding the solution.

Comment: You asked it to give you the size of the view and that’s what you got. If you want the device size, use this CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

Comment: When we use the option `Inferred`(in xib right pane) the root view is supposed to have the same size as `mainScreen` bounds.. Am i correct ?, if not, then we need to change the frame of root view in `viewDidLoad` of each view controller manually  ?